# UIScrollview won't scroll despite having the correct content size; textview subview frame also behaving strangely

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UITextView, which sets its text dynamically from an RSS feed. The textview is a subview of a UIScrollview. Ultimately, I am creating a mobile newspaper app, so the user should be able to scroll through the text (and other subviews).

After creating the views in IB, I added

```
NSString *sourceCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.URL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
sourceCode = [self parseHTMLText:sourceCode];
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(320,9999);
CGSize txtStringSize = [sourceCode sizeWithFont:self.body.font
                              constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize];
CGRect newlblFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, txtStringSize.height);
self.body.frame = newlblFrame; //body is the textview
self.body.text = sourceCode;
self.scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, self.body.frame.size.height+300); //scroll is scrollview
```

A typical NSLog will display `body frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 2088}} scrollview frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 417}} scrollview content size = {320, 2388}`

However, when I run the app, `body` maintains its interface builder height of around 196 and the scrollview won't scroll (when i move it, it just bounces back to its original position)

On a side note, when I try to manually change the frame of the textview with `CGRectMake`, the NSLog shows the correct height, but the view doesn't appear different. I made sure that it's hooked up correctly in IB, because I can adjust other properties, like background color.

EDIT:

After I set the `cliptoBounds` property of the textview to `NO`, the textview now adjusts its height and tries to show the entire text. However, it cuts off at the end of the screen, and I still cannot scroll.

Here is what I see currently. I made the scrollview background color gray for convenience. I'm not sure why part of the scrollview is partially in white and and partially gray. (Title) is a separate label btw)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always if some `UIView` contains the another class which is subclass of `UIView` and you need some action for this view please set  `parentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

I recommend you to check the hierarchy of views, maybe scrollview doesn't contain the text which you want to show, like

```
for (UIView *view in parentView.subviews){
    NSLog(@"%@", view);
}
```

Regards

Comment: Do you want to scroll all screen or only uitextview? If you put the text to the uitextview content size is automatically extended. Please post your code, because maybe i don't understand you properly

Comment: The code was posted above; the whole screen must scroll; the textview is one of several subviews

Comment: So firstly you need to extend the textView and move the rest in the scroll view. If the textView is stationary, better way is to use the UILabel, you can calculate the size for input text like, CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font minFontSize:10 actualFontSize:&actualFontSize forWidth:200 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];